# How to get hour and minute a time cell when it is more than 24:00 in EXCEL

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

When summing multiple excel cells which contain time durations (for instance the duration of the time an employee is present in the office for each day of a month), the sum gets bigger than 24:00 hours and we have to select a specific Type of Time Category in the Number tab in Format Cell (Normally it is named 37:30:55 for clarification). It works fine. But using the typical HOUR and MINUTE functions does not give the right HOUR part and MINUTE part of that summation.

For example in the image attached, the sum of durations is 126:06:00 and we expect the output 126 and 6 when using HOUR(D33) and MINUTE(D33) respectively. The MINUTE function works  fine, but seems the HOUR function always gets  confused.

[image]

Is there any other function that can help solve this issue?

Comment: @bigben your answer worked, Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As date/timeis just a double, use this formula:

```
=INT(A1*24)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works for this particular example. But when I add 4 hours to one of the cells and the summation is 124:06, the formula you suggested still shows 120

Comment: @mike with `124:06:00` in A1 with my formula I get `124`

Comment: @ScottCarner that is weird. I get 120. But with INT(D33)*24+HOUR(D33) it works.

Comment: I checked my calcs are automatic. Anyway, thanks for the hint, I learned something new.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `INT()`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent yes, otherwise it will return a double with the minute and seconds as the decimal.

Comment: The reason I ask is I put `=124/24+6/(24*60)` in cell **A1** and format **A1** as `[hh]:mm:ss` and your formula with the `INT()` gives me 120

Comment: **Ignore my comment**  ....................I put the 24 outside the `INT()`

Comment: I still get 124 @Gary'sStudent with your formula in A1 and mine in B1

Comment: You are correct! .............................my error!

Comment: @Mike did you do what Gary'sStudent did and use `INT(A1)*24` instead of `INT(A1*24)`?

Comment: @ScottCarner Yes I made the same mistake. Thanks. Wow I have worked  a lot with  excel and  done so much different and weird stuff with it many people could never imagine. But I never could have thought Excel also lets you multiply a number to a TIME! Excel is excellent. It is always full of surprises :)